# How to create directories in Android11

Tags: flutter, android-11

I have tried many ways gone through many solutions but none of them are working.

I am trying to create a folder for my app in `storage/emulated/0` but because of introduction of scoped storage in android 11, I guess I am not able to create the directory.

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
```

These are the permissions I have included in my `AndroidManifest.xml` and have set `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

I also tried removing `tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"` from the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission mentioned above.

When I am not including the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` peremission this is the error I am getting:

```
FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 'storage/emulated/0/myDir' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1
```

And when I am including the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission and asking for `Permission.manageExternalStorage` I am getting `No permissions found in manifest for: []22`